# How to prevent a self-referencing table from becoming circular

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, circular-reference

This is a pretty common problem but I haven't yet found the exact question and answer I'm looking for.

I have one table that has a FK pointing to its own PK, to enable an arbitrarily deep hierarchy, like the classic tblEmployee that has a column `Manager` that is a FK with the PK tblEmployee.EmployeeID.

Let's say in my app, the user

1. Creates new employees Alice and Dave, with no manager because they're the CEO and President. So `tblEmployee.Manager` is NULL for those two records.
2. Create new employee Bob, with Alice as manager. Then create Charles with Bob as his manager. Their Manager fields contain the Primary Key value of another record in `tblEmployee`.
3. Edit employee record for Alice, meaning to assign Dave has her manager (which would be fine) but accidentally set Alice's manager to be Charles, who is two levels down from Alice in the tree.

Now the table is in a circular reference instead of a proper tree.

What is the *best* way to make sure that Step 3 **cannot be done** in an application? I just need to make sure that it will refuse to do that last SQL update, and instead show some error message.

I'm not picky about whether it's a database constraint in SQL Server (has to work in 2008 or 2012) or with some kind of validation routine in the business logic layer of my C# app.

Comment: Business logic could be pretty straight forward: keep finding employee's manager until it's null, or it's an employee you've already encountered in the loop.

Comment: Have you considered using [`hierarchyid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) to model the hierarchy instead of the pointer model? By its very nature of the different way it models hierarchies, you cannot construct a cycle.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this with a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` that validates manager id is not a cycle.  You can't have complex queries in a check constraint, but if you wrap it in a function first you can:

```sql
create function CheckManagerCycle( @managerID int )
returns int
as
begin

    declare @cycleExists bit
    set @cycleExists = 0

    ;with cte as (
        select E.* from tblEmployee E where ID = @managerID
        union all
        select E.* from tblEmployee E join cte on cte.ManagerID = E.ID and E.ID <> @managerID
    )
    select @cycleExists = count(*) from cte E where E.ManagerID = @managerID

    return @cycleExists;

end
```

Then you can use a constraint like this:

```
alter table tblEmployee
ADD CONSTRAINT chkManagerRecursive CHECK ( dbo.CheckManagerCycle(ManagerID) = 0 )
```

This will prevent adding or updating records to create a cycle from any source.

---

**Edit:** An important note: check constraints are validated on the columns they reference.  I originally coded this to check cycles on the Employee ID, rather than the Manager ID.  However, that did not work because it only triggered on changes to the ID column.  This version does work because it is triggered any time the `ManagerID` changes.

Comment: My head asplode with the recursive definition of cte. Thank you very much for showing me this; I didn't know enough SQL to know that it could be done this way (I'm a C# developer who does SQL only because we don't have a big enough staff to have a resident DB guru)

Comment: _"This will prevent **adding** or updating records to create a cycle from any source."_ Are you sure? I tested it (postgresql), but to `chkManagerRecursive` evaluate to 1, the circular reference already had to be in the table (i.e., the constraint  catched only updates, but not inserts). Anyway, I adapted your function to run within an after insert or update row level trigger in postgresql and worked nice. Tks.

Comment: what would be the logical equivalent of this in c# ?

Comment: How in the hell does this only have 20 upvotes?  thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can add 'level' integer column.

Alice and Dave will have level == 0
If You will set manager for employee his (employee) level  will be level+1 of his manager.

During update You should check if manager level is smaller than level of employee...

This will be faster than using procedure...

Answer (score 1):

You can include a check in your `UPDATE` statement:

```
DECLARE @Employee INT = 2
       ,@NewManager INT = 4
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *
              FROM tblEmployee
              WHERE Manager = @Employee
              UNION  ALL
              SELECT a.*
              FROM tblEmployee a
              JOIN cte b
                ON a.manager = b.EmployeeID)
UPDATE a
SET a.Manager = @NewManager
FROM tblEmployee a
WHERE EmployeeID = @Employee
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM cte b
                    WHERE a.EmployeeID = b.Manager)
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/71f0d/5/0)

Comment: Woot I didn't know that you can do some recursive things with CTE ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it it's :

1. Create 2 **recursives functions** (Perform better than dirty loops) in t-sql that's will do the job of returning both a table of "*N+x managers of given employee*" and "*N-x employee of given manager*"
2. Prevent Step 3, use `GET_MANAGERS_OF` and `GET_EMPLOYEES_OF` function will be use in both :

   - Check in your C# App
   - Check in table Employee **TRIGGER** *(the best security cause you don't know if every developpers will check before update employee and if someone does directly sql update)*

If the **manager X** that you are assigning to **employee Y** it's not **employee N-x of Y**.

In any case, thoses recursives functions will be usefull in your SQL queries and C# App

FYI, there is a way to handle SQL ERROR TRANSACTION in C# App ("You can do do that because...").