# Finding circular references within PostgreSQL table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1, circular-reference

I have one table with attributes (ID int, SourceID int, TargetID int, TargetType int)

```
ID SourceID TargetID
---------------------
1   123       456  
2   456       789  
3   1         123  
4   456        1   
5   2          1
```

I want to find out all circular references. I want to write PL/pgsql function for this.

Here circular reference for ID 4 = 456 1 123 456

I want to find such instances. Can anyone suggest me how to proceed for this.

Comment: I assume this is for any degree of separation, not just 1 degree as in your example.

Comment: @ xQbert ..Yes..could you please suggest on this

Comment: Sounds like a graph traversal problem - probably done with a recursive CTE.

Answer (score 4):

This is similar to [How to prevent a self-referencing table from becoming circular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019384/how-to-prevent-a-self-referencing-table-from-becoming-circular) (SQL-Server version), which poses the question using a didatic example of employee/manager table.

Beyond a function to detect circular references I was interested having a trigger to prevent such data to be inserted or updated in the database.

Here is the code PLpgSQL/PostgreSQL I adapted from [mellamokb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019384/how-to-prevent-a-self-referencing-table-from-becoming-circular/23020112#23020112)'s answer:

```
-- example of table structure
CREATE TABLE employee (
   ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
   ManagerID INTEGER,
   CONSTRAINT a PRIMARY KEY (ID),
   CONSTRAINT b FOREIGN KEY (ManagerID) REFERENCES employee (ID))

-- function to be used inside trigger
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CircularReference()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
$$ 
DECLARE _CircularReferenceExists BIT(1) := 0;

BEGIN  

    WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
        SELECT E.* FROM employee E WHERE E.ID = new.ManagerID
        UNION -- union instead of union all to prevent infinite looping.
        SELECT E.* FROM employee E JOIN cte C ON C.ManagerID = E.ID AND E.ID <> new.ManagerID
    )
    SELECT count(*) INTO _CircularReferenceExists FROM cte C WHERE C.ManagerID = new.ManagerID;

    IF (SELECT _CircularReferenceExists <> B'0')
    THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Circular Reference found: ManagerID = %', new.ManagerID;
    END IF;

RETURN NEW;       
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- trigger
CREATE TRIGGER CircularReference
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE CircularReference();
```

If one already have data in the database just create the trigger and use an UPDATE statement to make it start detecting circular references.

```
UPDATE employee SET ID = ID;
```

Comment: 1. This algorithm checks a circular reference starts with the parent of employee, not the current one. Let's say, an elephant reports to giraffe, the giraffe reports to rhinoceros who does not report to anyone. If we try to assign the elephant as a manager of the rhinoceros, there are no any errors. To fix it, the condition `E.ID <> new.ManagerID` should be `E.ID <> new.ID`.
2. A circular reference should be checked only when updating. It's impossible that one of existent rows already references to a new row.
3. It's possible to make a self reference.

Comment: How a row can be referenced to a non-existent row yet? It's possible only if the `manager_id` field does not have a constraint. But in the code there is a constraint `REFERENCES employee (ID)`. If we add a new row, it means that no one references to it yet, right? Anyway, thanks for your example.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the recursive function below. The function uses [intarray extension.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/intarray.html)

```
create extension intarray;
```

The first element of int array `arr` is an `id`. The rest of the array contains consecutive references `source -> target.`

If the second and the last elements of the array are equal, then a circular reference was found. (1)

We must look for *inner circular references* and eliminate them (or we'll finish with stack overflow). (2)

```
create or replace function find_cref(arr int[])
returns setof int[] language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    vlen int = #arr;
    vtarget int;
begin
    if arr[2] = arr[vlen] then                                 -- (1)
        return query select arr;
    else
        if #uniq(sort(subarray(arr, 2)))+ 1 = vlen then        -- (2)
            for vtarget in
                select target from the_table where source = arr[vlen]
            loop
                return query select find_cref (arr+ vtarget);
            end loop;
        end if;
    end if;
end $$;

select c[1] id, subarray(c, 2) cref 
from (
    select find_cref(array[id, source, target]) c
    from the_table) x
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
CREATE TABLE members (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  reports_to_id int REFERENCES members(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION circular_reference() RETURNS trigger AS $$
  DECLARE circular_ref_exists boolean := false;
  BEGIN
    IF (NEW.reports_to_id = NEW.id)
    THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'A self reference has been detected';
    END IF;

    WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
      SELECT * FROM members
      WHERE members.id = NEW.reports_to_id
      UNION
      SELECT members.* FROM cte
      INNER JOIN members ON
        members.id = cte.reports_to_id AND
        members.id <> NEW.id
    )
    SELECT true INTO circular_ref_exists FROM cte WHERE reports_to_id = NEW.id;

    IF (circular_ref_exists)
    THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'A circular reference has been detected';
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER circular_reference
    BEFORE UPDATE ON members
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION circular_reference();
```